# Using chmod in PHP using wildcards doesn't work

Tags: php, chmod

It seems

`chmod("*.txt", 0660);`

doesn't work.

I know I can:

1. *chmod* the files one by one: it works but I do not know all the names in advance, so I cannot use it.
2. Use `exec`. It works but I don't like it for several reasons (speed, security, and so on).
3. Use `scandir`. It works but again, slow and I guess too much for a simple operation

I really want to use chmod directly. Is it even possible? Thank you.

Comment: Could you give more context to why you want to change permissions on files? You could do this at the point you write the files to the filesystem

Comment: That's a wonderful idea, at first I though it could be hard but... Is there a way to CREATE a file already with those attributes, or should I chmod them later?

Comment: And really, I would like to know WHY it has been downvoted and by whom. It's a totally legit question, I DEMONSTRATED I KNOW HOW TO DO IT in THREE DIFFERENT WAYS. Forgive me if I ask how I can do it in a fourth way. I was under the impression SO was to ask questions of which you didn't know the answer to. I guess somebody should really come to live with me in Pattaya.

Comment: Added an answer that I think will help. So I believe someone has marked the question down as the first sentence is chmod... doesn't work. But without any context, it does really help. Maybe say what you are trying to do. e.g. "I'm trying to iterate all of the files in a particular folder and change the permissions. I tried `chmod("*.txt", 0660);` but it didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can do this using `scandir` like you mentioned and yes filesystem can be pretty slow, you can add a check in so you do not do it to files you have already processed

```
<?php

$files = scandir('./');
foreach ($files as $file) {
    // check here so you don't have to do every file again
    if (substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms($file)), -4) === "0660") {
        echo "skipping " . $file; 
        continue;
    }

    $extension = pathinfo($file)['extension'];
    if ($extension === 'txt') {
        chmod($file, 0660);
    }
}
```

Or you could use `glob`

```
<?php

$files = glob('./*.{txt}', GLOB_BRACE);
foreach($files as $file) {
    // check here so you don't have to do every file again
    if (substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms($file)), -4) === "0660") {
        echo "skipping " . $file; 
        continue;
    }

    $extension = pathinfo($file)['extension'];
    if ($extension === 'txt') {
        chmod($file, 0660);
    }
}
```